# Create an index from another database in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing

I need to create a new index in my database each time sql database service is started.
For that, I use sp_procoption procedure. Whereas this procedure runs only from master database. I need to create new index in my database Bio_HO. How to create the index in Bio_HO from master database. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Anand

Comment: Huh? Why would you need to create the index each time the database service starts?

Comment: Unless I drop and recreate the index, the query works much slower, so that C# returns time out error.

Comment: You're fixing the wrong problem then, and you're doing it in the wrong way.